# NSStringFromPoint disappears under Objective-C++

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c++

The function NSStringFromPoint disappears when I compile my code using objective-C++, but it's fine under objective-C.

How can I make objective-C++ see that function?

If I compile under Objective-C++ it says:

```
error: 'NSStringFromPoint' was not declared in this scope
error: 'NSStringFromRect' was not declared in this scope
error: 'NSEqualSizes' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: What does "disappears" mean? The compiler claims there is no such function or calls to it silently fail or what?

Comment: Wow, there's an Obj-C++ ?? What a clash of mindsets that must be.

Comment: I think you need to show some code and possibly the compile statement that Xcode generates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but if you're linking against the iPhone SDK, there is no  `NSPoint` or `NSStringFromPoint`. UIKit uses the Core Graphics structs `CGPoint`, `CGSize` and `CGRect`. The equivalent function would be `NSStringFromCGPoint`.

The Simulator libraries do not quite match up with the iPhone libraries -- I'm fairly certain applications compiled for the simulator link against the Mac's own Foundation.framework. For example, I wasted a lot of time in the pre-2.0 days thinking that `NSXMLDocument` was available on iPhone because it compiled and ran in the simulator.

Comment: With your hint I was able to build the full translation dictionary from NS to CG.

Comment: Since `NSPoint` and `CGPoint` have the same layout, you can convert one to the other quite easily by doing this: `CGPoint cgPoint = *(CGPoint *)&nsPoint;`

Comment: Or use NSPointToCGPoint (or From for the other direction), or define `NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64` (or build 64-bit), which will make NSPoint and CGPoint exactly equal, so that no explicit conversion of any form is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled this simple application:

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
int main (void)
{
    NSLog (@"%@", NSStringFromPoint(NSMakePoint(10, 10));
    return 0;
}
```

Using this command line:

```
gcc -x objective-c++ test.mm -framework Cocoa -lstdc++
```

And I got this output (ignoring the error about no autorelease pool in place):

```
2010-05-12 12:41:33.946 a.out[290:10b] {10, 10}
```

Make sure you're including the right headers, at the very least, make sure you're importing `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`. An explicit `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` will do no harm if it has already been included.

Comment: As I stated, it works fine under objective-C. All the relevant (and irrelevant) headers are included

Comment: Well, @John, you have a couple of options since it's working fine elsewhere, just not in your environment. Are you using the same command line options as dreamlax? If you do _exactly_ what dreamlax did, does it work?

Comment: @dreamlax, why sometimes include and sometimes import in Obj-C? Is there a difference?

Comment: Also, I'm working with Foundation and UIKit (iphone programming) with the IDE. So the simple example is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @paxdiablo: It makes no difference in this case. `#import` in Objective-C just provides automatic include guards (or something along those lines, it just ensures that the header is only included once).

Comment: @John Smith: Perhaps appropriately tagging your question would give you more relevant results. There is nothing in your question or tags to indicate that this was the case.

Comment: @John Smith: Also, when I don't include/import `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` I get exactly the same error you do, except it says that `NSLog`, `NSMakePoint` and `NSStringFromPoint` were not declared in this scope.